# Frequent Wireless issues

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

One of my colleague is having frequent WiFi issues thus, the LAN is working fine. This set-up was not done by me but it was there for a longer time. He has his main router given by ISP (DHCP enabled + WiFi) connected to two switches that are distributing to all the end points withing his apartment.

[image]

However, three end points are connected to three individual routers (DHCP disabled) with WiFi enabled and some LANs are also used. Now, this set-up was working as per him without any issues until they change the internet service from **ADSL** to **Fiber GPON** service. Soon after the change we started having frequent WiFi slowness despite the router that we're getting connected to.

On an odd note, he also complains that some of his devices keep on asking for WiFi password whenever he goes out comes back to the WiFi range.

I do know that having many routers can cause issues but I'm still curious what could be the issue?

Comment: Have all the end-point routers been given static IPs outside the main router DHCP pool/scope? Additionally, have all the end-point routers been set to point their default gateway to the main router? Finally, and if he's being asked to enter his password all the time he reconnects, are his devices a little old and the new password is long/complex? Might be the older devices sending malformed data - seen this before with old Android + eduroam.

Comment: All the endpoint routers are outside the DHCP pool but within the same subnet. Yes, they are all set to default gateway, as the LAN works without any issues. Nope, the devices are new but two of the routers are quite old.

Comment: Have you changed all the end-point routers to have the same wifi settings as the main one???

Comment: Yes! same SSID, Key,... etc. However I have tried both with automatic and manual channels to make sure they're not interfering with each other.

Comment: Try factory resetting the end-point routers and reconfigure them, as you have done, to act as APs. Also, tell each device to forget all SSIDs associated with this network (past and present)...

Comment: These all have been done.. Thanks for the suggestions. However, I'm expecting more of technically challenged answer/comment as most of the things you've done are practiced.

Comment: If your question had all the steps you've tried then we wouldn't need to ask the basics first...  additionally, is the DHCP scope the same as the previous setup, not necessarily the cause but it may be linked...

Comment: Yes it was. He kept it as is, just to make sure he won't mess up with the system.